Spring Boot: UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'runController'
Can anyone please explain this to me, why am I getting an error in creating a bean in SpringBoot
I'm learning SpringBoot so have any idea why is this happening
I have attached the code of both the files generating error
This is the error I'm getting
2024-12-01T18:10:05.806+05:30  WARN 21088 --- [demo] [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'runController' defined in file [C:\Users\91940\Desktop\demo\build\classes\java\main\com\example\demo\run\RunController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'runRepository' defined in file [C:\Users\91940\Desktop\demo\build\classes\java\main\com\example\demo\run\RunRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute database script

// RunController
package com.example.demo.run;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/runs")
public class RunController {
    private final RunRepository runRepository;

    @Autowired
    public RunController(RunRepository runRepository) {
        this.runRepository = runRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    List<Run> findAll() {
        return runRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    Run findById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Optional<Run> run = runRepository.findById(id);
        if (run.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RunNotFoundException();
        }
        return run.get();
    }

    // post
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping("")
    void create(@Valid @RequestBody Run run) {
        runRepository.create(run);
    }

    // put
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    void update(@Valid @RequestBody Run run, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        runRepository.update(run, id);
    }

    // delete
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    void delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        runRepository.delete(id);
    }
}

//RunRepository
package com.example.demo.run;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


@Repository
@Configuration
public class RunRepository {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunRepository.class.getName());
    private final JdbcClient jdbcClient;

    @Autowired
    public RunRepository(JdbcClient jdbcClient) {
        this.jdbcClient = jdbcClient;
    }

    public List<Run> findAll() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM RUN";
        return jdbcClient.sql(query)
                .query(Run.class)
                .list();
    }

    public Optional<Run> findById(Integer id) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM RUN WHERE id= ?";
        return jdbcClient.sql(query)
                .param(id)
                .query(Run.class)
                .optional();
    }

    public void create(Run run) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO RUN(id,title,started_on,completed_on,miles,location) VALUES(:v)";
        var update = jdbcClient.sql(query)
                .param("v", List.of(run.id(), run.title(), run.startedOn(), run.completedOn(), run.miles(),
                        run.location().toString()))
                .update();

        Assert.state(update == 1, "Failed to create activity: " + run.title());
    }

    public void update(Run run, Integer id) {
        String query = "UPDATE RUN SET title=?, started_on=?, completed_on=?, miles=?, location=? WHERE id=?";
        int update = 0;
        try {
            update = jdbcClient.sql(query)
                    .params(List.of(run.title(), run.startedOn(), run.completedOn(), run.miles(), run.location().toString(),
                            id))
                    .update();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        Assert.state(update == 1, "Failed to update activity: " + run.title());
    }

    public void delete(Integer id) {
        String query = "DELETE FROM RUN WHERE id=?";
        var update = jdbcClient.sql(query)
                .param(id)
                .update();

        Assert.state(update == 1, "Failed to delete activity: " + id);
    }

    public int count() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM RUN";
        return jdbcClient.sql(query)
                .query(Run.class)
                .list().size();
    }

    public void saveAll(List<Run> runs) {
        runs.forEach(this::create);
    }

    public List<Run> findByLocation(String location) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM RUN WHERE location=?";
        return jdbcClient.sql(query)
                .param(location)
                .query(Run.class)
                .list();
    }
}


Have you actually read the error? The problem isn't those 2 files but your data.sql and/or schema.sql.

Thanks @M.Deinum
I got your point. I have reconfigured that stuff that you mentioned and now it's working fine.
